# html scraping using lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I'm scrapping data using `lxml`

This is the inspect element of single post

```
<article id="post-4855" class="post-4855 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">


<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="http://aitplacements.com/uncategorized/cybage/" rel="bookmark">Cybage..</a></h1>
            <div class="entry-meta">
        <span class="byline"> Posted by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://aitplacements.com/author/tpoait/">TPO</a></span></span><span class="posted-on"> on <a href="http://aitplacements.com/uncategorized/cybage/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="2017-09-13T11:02:32+00:00">September 13, 2017</time></a></span><span class="comments-link"> with <a href="http://aitplacements.com/uncategorized/cybage/#respond">0 Comment</a></span>      </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <p>cybage placement details shared <a href="http://aitplacements.com/uncategorized/cybage/" class="read-more">READ MORE</a></p>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

For every such post, I want to extract title, content of post, and post timing.

For example in above, the details will be

```
{title : "Cybage..",
 post : "cybage placement details shared"
 datetime="2017-09-13T11:02:32+00:00"
}
```

Till now what I'm able to achieve:
the website requires login, I'm successfull in doing that.

For extracting information:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
Chrome/42.0.2311.90'}
url = 'http://aitplacements.com/news/'
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
#print doc # it prints <Element html at 0x7f59c38d2260>
raw_title = doc.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/a/@href/text()')
print raw_title
```

The raw_title gives empty value `[]` ?

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You should take a look at [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It is great for your need. Or also `scrapy`, if you need something more advanced (e.g., spiders).

Comment: I was getting empty value, because I was getting logged off, fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

`@href` refers to the value of the `href` attribute:

```
In [14]: doc.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/a/@href')
Out[14]: ['http://aitplacements.com/uncategorized/cybage/']
```

You want the text of the `<a>` element instead:

```
In [16]: doc.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/a/text()')
Out[16]: ['Cybage..']
```

Therefore, use

```
raw_title = doc.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/a/text()')
if len(raw_title) > 0:
    raw_title = raw_title[0]
else:
    # handle the case of missing title
    raise ValueError('Missing title')
```

Comment: Why I'm getting empty `raw_title`, the doc does extracts the page right?

Comment: If you are uncertain what `doc` has parsed, print `LH.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)` (or write it to a file and inspect it there). The reason you were getting an empty `raw_title` is because `a/@href/text()` is looking for text attached to the `href` attribute. There is none. The text is attached to the `<a>` element.

Comment: the problem was I was getting logged off again, fixed the problem